# What is the fastest way to transfer data from watch to phone Android wear

Tags: android, wear-os, google-api-client

I am trying to move a slider on a phone to reflect to a slider on the watch. It is working but the problem is that if I move the slider up and down fast there is a long delay so that my changes take a second or so for the reflection to catch up. I'm using a PutDataMapRequest to communicate through GoogleApiClient. I guess my real question is there a way to do this faster. I'm just wanting to send an int and a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using DataApi? If so, use MessageApi and send a message via sendMessage(); that would be faster. In addition, you may want to optimize how much data you want to set; for example, it may be enough to send the "progress" when the seekbar is stopped and not changing any more; that means no data needs to be sent while it is moving. If that is too little, you may decide to do a bit of rate control before sending data; for example if your seekbar can change between 0 to 100, you most likely don't need to send a message with every change, you can say, for example, send a message when seekbar changes by 3 units and when the seekbar stops changing, send the final value to remain accurate at the end of the process.

Comment: I just came back to update my post. I found that if I throttled back to only sending the progress updates at 100ms, that calmed things down quite a bit. I was looking at MessageApi and may try that as well but either way, your post is the right answer.